# how to update specific object in array which match conditions

Tags: mongodb

actually i want to update specific object in my documents array which has `viewProfile : true` but it's gonna update all elements in array
here is my query:

```
const user = await User.updateMany(
    {
      _id: req.userData.id,
      "notifications.viewProfile" : true
    },
    {
      $set: {
        "notifications.$[].read": false
      }
    }
  );
```

consider this document

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4ae76bd4e24418a020b665"),
    "username" : "test",
    "notifications" : [ 
        {
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-18T19:22:24.809Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e4c397075265a36203dab5a"),
            "message" : "testone is now following you.",
            "viewProfile" : false,
            "read" : false
        }, 
        {
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-02-18T19:22:29.200Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e4c397575265a36203dab5d"),
            "message" : "testone is now following you.",
            "viewProfile" : true,
            "read" : false
        }
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filtered positional operator `$[<identifier>]` . Reference https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

```
const user = await User.update(
   {
      _id: req.userData.id
   },
   { $set: {  "notifications.$[element].read": false } },
   { 
     multi: true,
     arrayFilters: [ { "element.viewProfile": true } ]
   }
)
```